Proving the minimization of variance in the Vegas algorithm
According to this article enter link description here
The uncertainty in a Monte Carlo integration gives
\begin{equation} \tag{1} \sigma^2_F=\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_i \int_{x_i}^{x_i+∆x_i} J_if^2(x)\:dx-F^2\right) \end{equation}
with $J_i=N_g∆x_i$ is a step function.
Treating the $J_i$ as independent variables, subject to the constrain
\begin{equation}
\sum_i\frac{∆x_i}{J_i}=1
\end{equation}
G. Peter Lepage says that it is easy to show that $\sigma^2_F$ is minimized when
\begin{equation}
\frac{J_i^2}{∆x_i}\int_{x_i}^{x_i+∆x_i}f^2(x)dx=constant
\end{equation}
I want to ask.
Is the Lagrange multiplier method used here to prove this?
\begin{equation} \tag{2} L=\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_i \int_{x_i}^{x_i+∆x_i} J_if^2(x)\:dx-F^2\right)+\lambda \left(\sum_i\frac{∆x_i}{J_i} -1      \right)
\end{equation}
Partial derivatives with respect to each $J_i$, I have:
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\frac{\partial L}{ \partial J_i}=\frac{1}{N} \int_{x_i}^{x_i+∆x_i} f^2(x)\:dx-\lambda\frac{∆x_i}{J_i^2}=0
\end{equation}
Solve equation (3) for $J_i$, have:
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\frac{1}{N} \int_{x_i}^{x_i+∆x_i} f^2(x)\:dx=\lambda\frac{∆x_i}{J_i^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
J_i^2= \frac{\lambda N∆x_i}{\int_{x_i}^{x_i+∆x_i} f^2(x)\:dx}
\end{equation}
Because $\lambda N$ is a constant, so:
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
\frac{J_i^2}{∆x_i}\int_{x_i}^{x_i+∆x_i} f^2(x)\:dx=constant
\end{equation}
I have again $J_i,∆x_i,N$ is always positive so λ>0, therefore:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 L}{ \partial J_i^2}=2\lambda\frac{∆x_i}{J_i^3}>0
\end{equation}
That is, equation (1) is minimized when it satisfies (5)
I don't know if this proof is correct. Is there any solution to prove that equation (1) is close to 0?. I tried Cauchy inequality but I found it not satisfactory for sum of integrals.
\begin{equation}
\sum_i{\int_{x_i}^{x_i+∆x_i} J_if^2(x)\:dx}\sum_i{\int_{x_i}^{x_i+∆x_i} \frac{1}{J_i}\:dx}
≥\left(\sum_i\int_{x_i}^{x_i+∆x_i} \sqrt{J_i}|f(x)|\frac{1}{\sqrt{J_i}}\:dx \right)^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_i{\int_{x_i}^{x_i+∆x_i} J_if^2(x)\:dx}
≥\left(\sum_i\int_{x_i}^{x_i+∆x_i}  |f(x)|\:dx \right)^2≥F^2
\end{equation}
I feel like this doesn't seem right.
Anyone with a solution, please help me. Thanks a lot.
